# The 10k privileges page needs revision to introduce users to *where* the 10k tools are

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, help-center, privileges-page

A few days ago, I reached the 10k mark on another Stack Exchange site - and for the first time on any Stack Exchange site (yay!). I read through the [moderator privileges page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) that morning. And it didn't take me long to become confused.

**The privileges page is missing crucial advice** on where, exactly, one can find the moderator tools, or the many lists discussed.

After several attempts to track this new stuff down, I simply began to wonder if the many lists mentioned simply didn't exist anymore (and someone had forgotten to update the page), if the moderator tools page I *thought* existed didn't, and if the flags only showed up somehow when there were any needing attention.

Well, it isn't entirely missing. But it's easy to miss. This morning, I finally happened to notice *this link*:

[image: The third link on the privilege page links to the moderator tools!]

***It really does exist!*** *And so do all those lists!*

Of the nine links on that very big page, only two of them actually link to the moderator tools, and they're the only parts of the page that say "Here they are!", and they're buried in amongst other information and apparently, they were easy to miss.

I'm not sure that should be all that surprising either: I was excited to have finally hit 10k, was glancing over all the information I could, hunting for the new stuff, and just generally not reading the entire page straight through from top to bottom for a lot of reasons.

### The page should have a section which simply states where the tools & lists are

The section should be at the top and simply say:

- Where the lists are found (inside the moderator tools!), and
- Where the link to the moderator tools can be found, for future reference. (Apparently it's on the Review page, in the top left above the review queue links)

It should have a relevant heading, since people will be looking for it.

Comment: As for your second bullet point, you can access the tools by clicking on the review link in the top-bar. There should now be a "Tools" link next to the "Review" title above all the review queues that you can click.

Comment: @animuson I added that information to the question for reference. I realise I didn't say: thanks for pointing that out. It's good to know there is a link.

Comment: @animuson: That grayed-out breadcrumb (or is it supposed to be a tab? I can't really tell) is also really easy to miss. Something should be done about that too, if people are actually meant to find the 10k tools that way. (And I'm saying this as someone who hit 10k on SO about a year ago, but only realized last month that there's more to the tools than just the flag review page linked from the top bar.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heh, thanks for the reminder. I re-wrote about half of that page the other day, adding links to the stuff I was talking about along the way. Could probably still use some linkage love, but I'll save that for when we start adding new analytics.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that you did that. I do think it could do with adding a couple more links, like [here](http://i.imgur.com/yzaVEeR.png) and at the _top_ of the _Access moderator tools_ section, but consider that it should probably also point out how to reach it in the future: go to Review, click Tools (plus a screenshot of where the Tools link is, since... well, take note of Ilmari's comment above, it's easy to miss)